# Adapt Access 2000 Split Database to SQL Backend

Tags: ms-access-2000

I have an Access 2000 Database created over a decade ago. The original creators are long gone. It's stored in a shared folder on a file server on the local network. The file was over 250MB in size, and is accessed by anywhere from a dozen to two dozen local users on the network. We still use Access 2000 loaded on the machines to open the file. I've also already split the database using Access's split tool, into a FE and BE file in order to try and speed things up. We're currently using the FE/BE approach, accessing a single FE file stored on the server as well.

I'm trying to figure out what else I can do to try and optimize it. Move the BE into a SQL server? Put a local copy of the FE on each machine? Set myself on fire and hope for the best?

We are looking to replace the DB, but plans are at least a year or longer down the pipeline at best.

Comment: An update a year later- It still runs slow, but I implemented a script to copy the FE file to the local user's machine, and set the shortcuts to point to that script. This helped.